# tar: don't change date if file is the same

Tags: tar

I'm using tar to extract files during a deployment process. I've noticed that systemctl issues a warning that daemon-reload must be run if a .service file has its timestamp changed, even if the file contents remain the same.

How can I configure tar to not change the file date if the file contents are unchanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a feature any implementation of tar that I'm aware of has (they all extract in place directly; at no point the content of an existing file is considered). The point is that the file actually **is** getting completely overwritten, even if just with the same content it had before.

So, there's no way to achieve that with tar alone.

If you can extract to a temporary directory first, and then use `rsync` to copy over only the files with changes, that would be different. However, note that this needs additional storage and night take significantly longer, depending on the temporary storage.

> issues a warning

So, a warning is a warning, not a problem. If you know nothing has changed, ignore it. But if nothing has changed, rubbing the daemon reload has no adverse effect, either.

Comment: I think I will have to get the file's md5 and mtime, `tar x`, then md5 again. If it has changed, I will set the old time.

Comment: That is pretty much was rsync does. Hence my recommendation of rsync.